# Constructing histogram from 2 variables in 1 column in R

Tags: r

I have a csv which utilises only 1 column with data separated by a space. Called Uniq.csv

The numbers represents how many tweets the person has done, the name is that persons twitter name.

```
2 Bobby
1 Derek
1 John
```

I'm attempting to create a histogram from this data. Ideally each account name on the x axis and their tweet frequency on the y.

Here's my code at attempting this:

```
setwd(setwd("~/Documents")
UniqFreq <- read.csv("Uniq.csv",header = FALSE)
hist(UniqFreq)
```

Of course this isn't working. Any help or assistance would go along way!

Comment: bar plot is good for this type of problem

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started:

```
barplot(  x$V1, names.arg = x$V2 )
```

yields

[image]

Thr first agument is the vector with the values that are to be plotted and the second provides the x lables. There are many more screws for finetuning (titles, axis lables, colours ...) but that would go beyond the scope here I think.

Comment: Could you explain what each part means. So I know what to replace and change for my specific set up

Comment: Edited but the better way is probably to look up `?barplot`

Answer (score 1):

1.) CSV stands for Comma-Separated Values.  Your values clearly aren't comma-separated.  Therefore, you should be using `read.table` and setting the `sep` argument to the proper value.

2.) Histograms are not for plotting categorical data (i.e. histograms do not have categorical variables on the X-axis, as you've specified here).  You are looking for a barchart.

So you could do this:

```
txt <- (
'2 Bobby
1 Derek
1 John'
)

dat <- read.table(text = txt, header = F, sep = " ", col.names = c("Count", "Name"))

barplot(height = dat$Count, names.arg = dat$Name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The question given said histogram but I was also confused as i thought bar chart was more appropriate. Only issue I'm having now is that the count and name are in the same column.

Comment: I addressed that too.  Use `read.table`, with `sep = " "`, not `read.csv`.

Comment: as your text file is called txt. I've replaced the code with Uniq.txt but im getting an error saying its not found...

Comment: I just used the txt variable as an example. You can leave your code as "Uniq.csv." So, `dat <- read.table(file = "Uniq.csv", header = F, sep = " ")`

Comment: If i try that code with the col.names part I get an error saying theres more columns then names. Which isnt true. If i remove that section it says line 247 did not have 5 elements, whatever does that mean...

Comment: It means there is some sort of inconsistency in the format within your file. Perhaps a missing space between variables on line 247? Or perhaps an extra variable on line 247?    You can try setting `fill=TRUE`, although this won't really fix the problem.  There isn't much you can do, except inspect your file, figure out where the issue is, and fix it.