# How do I create a histogram in r for a 2 column data?

Tags: r, histogram

`user_a - 3
user_b - 4
user_c - 1
user_d - 4`
I want to show the distribution over number of tweets per author in r using a histogram. The original file has 1048575 such rows
I did `hist(df$twitter_count, nrow(df))` but I don't think its correct

Comment: please include your data as editable text instead of link to an image

Comment: Hi Mehru - welcome to SO... it would help me help you if I knew a little more about your data - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.   Your nrow(df) is speficying the breaks in the histogram... If you are looking at doing some conditional histograms (e.g. number of tweets per day/week/month/year per author) you might consider using lattice or ggplot2.

Comment: If you want the histogram of twitter counts, just use `hist(df$twitter_count)`

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46860454/constructing-histogram-from-2-variables-in-1-column-in-r/46860693#46860693)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constructing histogram from 2 variables in 1 column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46860454/constructing-histogram-from-2-variables-in-1-column-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each row of the data.frame represents a user -

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(user = letters, twitter_count = rpois(26, lambda = 4) + 1)
hist(df$twitter_count)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems I have misunderstood the question. I think following could be
what the OP is looking for.

```
df <- data.frame(user = letters, 
                 twitter_count = sample.int(200, 26))

ggplot(df, aes(user, twitter_count)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

---

Assuming you are looking for multiple histograms.

Replace `user` with respective variable name in your data.frame.

```
# Example data
df <- data.frame(user = iris$Species, 
                 twitter_count= round(iris[, 1]*10))

# Histograms using ggplot2 package
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = twitter_count)) +
  geom_histogram() + facet_grid(.~user)
```

Best to use an alternative method to see the distributions of twitter counts if your data contain many twitter users.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said, distribution for 'each user', I think it should be a bar blot:

```
require(data.table)
dat <- fread("
  user_a - 3
  user_b - 4
  user_c - 1
  user_d - 4"
)

barplot( names.arg = dat$V1, as.numeric(dat$V3) )
```

[barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz6nN.png)

or if you are looking for histograms, then:

```
hist(as.numeric(dat$V3), xlab = "", main="Histogram")
```

[histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2PbX.png)